# Getting maple to output graphs/charts in a vector graphics format

Tags: latex, vector-graphics, maple

I've drawn some histograms and time series graphs in Maple 13 that I'd like to output as vector graphics (ideally pdf, but eps or svg or whatever would be ok too). This is because I want to `\include` them in a LaTeX document, and the pngs I have so far look all bitmappy and ugly. How do I get Maple to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just right click and select "export as eps". I'm not entirely sure how I missed this...

Comment: Yes But this only show it as vector grapihcs if it is 2 graphs. For 3D it is not vector graphics.